# How can I let the user edit a number input in Mobile Safari when it has automatically inserted commas in?

Tags: ios, html, mobile-safari

Mobile Safari automatically inserts commas when using a number input (). That is fine. However, when you try to edit one of these large numbers, it does not let you unless you manually delete the commas.

Example: 
* Type in "500000"
* Mobile Safari turns it into "500,000"
* Try to delete the last 0 in the number to turn the number into "50000" or "50,000"
* It doesn't work.

Note: Deleting one of the first two 0s such that the number turns into "50,000" and has correct commas works. It's really the fact that safari won't let you edit it in a way that makes the comma incorrect. Is there an easy way to turn this on? I guess we could manually use javascript and listen to every number typed and then manipulate the value? Or we could switch the input to "tel" and not have the commas?

Comment: You can prevent it from inserting the commas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824874/is-there-a-way-to-stop-mobile-safari-inserting-commas-into-number-fields-on-html

Comment: yeah but is there a way to let "500,000" turn into "50,000" by deleting the last 0?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know the answer; otherwise I would have posted it. Removing the commas could be a workaround.